# Google Sheets - how do you open a CSV with Chinese characters in Unicode?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a CSV file with Chinese characters in it. The Chinese characters are encoded in Unicode (for example &#39321;).

How can I open or import this CSV file in Google Sheets, and have the Chinese characters display correct, I mean to have the Chinese characters display as the actual Chinese characters (for example &#39321; should be displayed as 香)?

[image: Part of my CSV, with Chinese characters encoded in Unicode]

If Google sheets cannot decode and display the Unicode in actual Chinese characters, then, can Excel do it?

The following is a very simple example, of such a CSV file content, just two lines.

```
Product Title
&#39321;&#36771;&#29482;
```

Comment: can you give a piece of grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decode with

```
function decode(code = '&#39321;'){
  var char = String.fromCharCode(code.match(/&#(\d+);/)[1]);
  console.log(char)
}
```

[String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

```js
      var code = '&#39321;'
      var char = String.fromCharCode(code.match(/&#(\d+);/)[1]);
      console.log(char)
```

### example of decoding from sheet

if you have already upload your data, use this to decode

```
function decode(){
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var data=sh.getDataRange().getValues()
  data.forEach((rng, row) => {
    rng.forEach((r, col) => {
      code = (ExtractAllRegex(r, '&#([0-9]+);', 1))
      code.forEach(function (c) { r = r.replace(`&#${c};`, String.fromCharCode(c)) })
      data[row][col] = r
    })
  });
  sh.getDataRange().setValues(data)
}
function ExtractAllRegex(input, pattern,groupId) {
  return Array.from(input.matchAll(new RegExp(pattern,'g')), x=>x[groupId]);
}
```

### example of csv parsing from url

```
function importCsvFromUrlCodeHtml(){
  // enable service google sheets api
  var url = 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.csv'
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  code = (ExtractAllRegex(data, '&#([0-9]+);', 1))
  code.forEach(function (c) { data = data.replace(`&#${c};`, String.fromCharCode(c)) })
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.clear();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var req = { pasteData: { data: data, delimiter: ",", coordinate: { sheetId: sh.getSheetId() } } };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: [req]}, ss.getId());
}
function ExtractAllRegex(input, pattern,groupId) {
  return Array.from(input.matchAll(new RegExp(pattern,'g')), x=>x[groupId]);
}
```

### example of csv parsing from drive

```
function importCsvFromIdCodeHtml() {
  var id = '13tlu9eYb5Ty3L45_RKibsfHjOXyUxeX3';
  var csv = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  csvData.forEach((rng, row) => {
    rng.forEach((r, col) => {
      code = (ExtractAllRegex(r, '&#([0-9]+);', 1))
      code.forEach(function (c) { r = r.replace(`&#${c};`, String.fromCharCode(c)) })
      csvData[row][col] = r
    })
  });
  var f = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  f.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}

function ExtractAllRegex(input, pattern,groupId) {
  return Array.from(input.matchAll(new RegExp(pattern,'g')), x=>x[groupId]);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am opening the CSV file in Google Sheets, how do I use such a decode function in Google Sheets?

Comment: I have edited my question, to add a simple example of the content of the CSV file.

Comment: Could you please explain how to achieve this? Are we using the function decode, or the function importCsvFromIdCodeHtml? Can this be applied to Google Sheets?

Comment: I have CSV files in my local drive, which I want to open in Google Sheets. In my CSV files, there could be characters in unicode, which I want to display in their actual characters (decoded). How can I make use of your functions to do this? I am not familiar with Google Sheets, not to mention the script editor.

Comment: I tried using your file, on my CSV file. My CSV file has a few rows and columns and one of the column has Chinese characters encoded in Unicode. But, after running your script, the result turns out to be error. Please see screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8DnH.png

Comment: it seems that your file is not a csv file!